# System.NotSupportedException: 'Undable to activate instance of type SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKCanvasViewRenderer from native handle'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am trying to replace `ContentView.Content` by touch.
However, if I touch `ContentView`, I got a strange exception like below.

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Undable to activate instance of type SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKCanvasViewRenderer from native handle'

### Reproduce procedure

1. Create blank Xamarin project.
2. Add 'MyContetView.cs' file.
3. copy & paste source code

```
    public class MyContentView : ContentView
    {
        private string _text;
        private SKCanvasView _canvasView;
        private Editor _editorView;

        public MyContentView()
        {
            _text = "Hello, World!";

            _canvasView = new SKCanvasView()
            {
                WidthRequest = 100,
                HeightRequest = 100,
                EnableTouchEvents = true
            };
            _canvasView.PaintSurface += (sender, e) =>
            {
                e.Surface.Canvas.Clear();

                var rect = new SKRect(0, 0, 
                    (float)(Width * Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density), 
                    (float)(Height * Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density));
                var rectPaint = new SKPaint()
                {
                    Color = SKColors.Red,
                    IsStroke = false,
                    StrokeWidth = 1
                };
                e.Surface.Canvas.DrawRect(rect, rectPaint);

                var textPaint = new SKPaint()
                {
                    Color = SKColors.Black,
                    IsAntialias = true,
                    TextSize = 16
                };
                e.Surface.Canvas.DrawText(_text, 0, 0, textPaint);
            };
            _canvasView.Touch += (sender, e) =>
            {
                ToggleContent();
                e.Handled = true;
            };

            _editorView = new Editor()
            {
                AutoSize = EditorAutoSizeOption.TextChanges
            };

            _editorView.Completed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                _text = _editorView.Text;
            };
            _editorView.Unfocused += (sender, e) =>
            {
                ToggleContent();
            };

            _canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
            Content = _canvasView;
        }

        public void ToggleContent()
        {
            if (Content == _canvasView)
            {
                Content = _editorView;
            }
            else
            {
                _canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                Content = _canvasView;
            }
        }
    }
```

4. Run
5. Touch

[Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11757)

### 2020.08.13 Update

I created an [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11757) on *Xamarin.Forms* because replacing `ContentView.Content` should be working because `SKCanvasView` inherits `View` like other *Xamarin.Froms*.

#### Workaround

Instead of replacing `ContentView.Content`, toggle `VisualElement.IsVisible` between `SKCanvasView` and `Editor`.

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="CanvasView"
                                          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                                          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
                                          IsVisible="True" 
                                          EnableTouchEvents="True"/>
        <Editor x:Name="EditorView"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
                     IsVisible="False"
                     AutoSize="TextChanges" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

```
public void ToggleState()
{
            if (isCanvasView)
            {
                CanvasView.IsVisible = true;
                CanvasView.Focus();

                EditorView.IsVisible = false;
                EditorView.Unfocus();
            }
            else
            {
                CanvasView.IsVisible = false;
                CanvasView.Unfocus();

                EditorView.IsVisible = true;
                EditorView.Focus();
            }
}
```

For cleaner code, **State** pattern could be a great solution than `if`.

Comment: This issue is related to you cannot use `Editor` to replace `SKCanvasView` .If you just use `SKCanvasView` draw a red box, I suggest you to use the Boxview to replace it. Here is running GIF. https://imgur.com/a/K4OM70Q

Comment: I used a Stacklayout to wrap the `boxView`, Then use `  sl.Children[0] = _editorView;` to replace it.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT So...  I can replace `Contnet` from Label to Editor, but can't replace from SKCanvasView to Editor?

Comment: Yes, I test it, cannot replace from SKCanvasView to Editor. but xamarin forms. Label , Button or BoxView can replace to the Editor.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thanks for checking out my issue. IMHO, `SKCanvasView` should be replaceable like other `View`. So... I think it is a kind of bug. Therefore, I create an issue on Github.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your update.